# Can I use only GrammarKit to generate both parser and lexer for Intellij Plugin development (custom lang)

Tags: intellij-plugin, jflex, grammar-kit

In the [tutorial of custom language support](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support_tutorial.html) for Intellij Plugin development, it [uses GrammarKit to generate the Parser](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/grammar_and_parser.html) and [JFlex (patched) to generate the Lexer](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/lexer_and_parser_definition.html).

On [this page](https://www.plugin-dev.com/intellij/introduction/#lexer-and-parser) the author says we can "use the GrammarKit plugin to generate lexer and parser".

Is there a particular reason that JetBrains suggest using JFlex to generate the lexer? How different the process would be if we use GrammarKit to generate both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I know the answer now.
The short answer is NO. It is a little bit complex than that.

Grammar-Kit can be used to generate `.flex` file and you still need JFlex generator to generate the Java lexer.

Both steps can be done via the context menu.

See [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit/#user-content-general-usage-instructions) for more info.